# make sure two fields in array are unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make sure the follower_id and followed_id are unique in an array which also includes a third number, called value. All are integers. It is the combination of follower_id and followed_id that needs to be unique not the individual numbers themselves. Here is what I have

```
Relationship.populate 1..20 do |relationship|
        relationship.follower_id = (1..20)
        relationship.followed_id = (1..20)
        relationship.value = rand(1..5)
        end
```

this would ensure that

```
1,3,5
1,3,5
2,3,5
1,2,5
```

would be

```
1,3,5
2,3,5
1,2,5
```

Comment: I believe the answer you selected is incorrect. (See my comment below.) Why would you give an example where are the random variates are the same (`5`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [[1,3,5], [1,3,4], [3,1,2], [2,3,2], [2,3,1], [1,2,3]]
```

If the order of the first two elements of each element of `a` is important:

```
a.uniq { |e| e[0,2] }
  #=> [[1, 3, 5], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If the order of the first two elements of each element of `a` is not important:

```
require 'set'
a.uniq { |e| Set.new e[0,2] } 
  #=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Excuse my newbiness but how to implement this with the code I posted

Comment: Sebastian, implementation seems to be a Rails issue, and I'm afraid I don't know Rails. Be that as it may, you have a class (or possibly module) method `populate` which takes one argument (`(1..20)` in the example) and a block. What does `populate` do (e.g., does it create instances of `Relationship` with values for certain instances variables)?  Readers: If any of you can help with this, please chime in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that the order in pairs is not to be taken into account, and you want to eliminate triples, even having different `value`s, here you go:

```
a = [[1,3,5], [3,1,5], [2,3,5], [2,3,6], [1,2,5]]
# to count [1,3,5] and [3,1,5] as similar
a.group_by { |(fd,fr,_)| [fd,fr].sort }.values.map &:first
# to count [1,3,5] and [3,1,5] as different
a.group_by { |(fd,fr,_)| [fd,fr] }.values.map &:first
#⇒ [[1,3,5], [3,1,5], [2,3,5], [1,2,5]]
```

Comment: Excuse my newbiness but how to implement this with the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

### Perfect Uniqueness

Here's a solution assuming the order within the triples matters and you want each **triple to be perfectly unique**. Just use the `uniq` method on the `Array` class. It works like this:

```
[
  [1,3,5], 
  [1,3,5],
  [2,3,5],
  [1,2,5]
].uniq

#=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 5]]
```

### Partial Uniqueness

If instead, you only care about **the first two being unique**, pass the `uniq` method a block that returns whatever subset you want to be unique. If you only want the first two elements of the triple and can discard duplicates *even when the third element is unique*, you can just pass it the range `0..1`.

```
[
  [1,3,5], 
  [1,3,5],
  [2,3,5],
  [1,2,5],
  [1,2,6]
].uniq { |triple| triple[0..1] }

#=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 5]]
```

Note that the last element, `[1,2,6]` was discarded even though it ended in `6` because it was considered a duplicate of `[1,2,5]`. This is because `[1,2,5][0..1] #=> [1,2]` and `[1,2,6][0..1] #=> [1,2]`.

Comment: This only works (as I understand the question), when the last elements of each element (array) of the array are the same (here, `5`). As those values are randomly drawn, that's not likely to happen often.